# Jmeter JMS Point-to-Point Sampler - Wire format negotiation timeout

Tags: jmeter

How to fix `wire format negotiation` timeout issue in JMeter when sending messages with JMS Point-to-Point sampler?

I have gone through the probable causes provided by apache at this link - http://activemq.apache.org/javaxjmsjmsexception-wire-format-negociation-timeout-peer-did-not-send-his-wire-format.html - no luck.

Here is the error message:

`jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format. javax.jms.JMSException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.at rg.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:62)`

Same properties if set in LoadRunner, I am able to send messages successfully using **Java over HTTP protocol**.

I also monitored network using `netstat` when running JMeter and LoadRunner. 
What I could see is JMeter connection always goes to `'CLOSE_WAIT'` status whereas Loadrunner connection goes to `'SYN_SENT' 'ESTABLISHED'` - as expected.

I have added `keystore` and `ciphersuite` to `system.properties` and can see `keystore created OK` in JMeter logs but nothing specific for ciperhsuite.

Could that be the issue?

Been stuck with this exception for about a week now, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your JMeter log details.

Comment: Not able to post full logs, but below is what I see: 2017/05/04 10:27:17 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format. javax.jms.JMSException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.
 at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:62)
 at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1206)